# Алгоритм равномерного распределения элементов в матрице

Tags: c#, массивы, arraylist

Необходимо сгенерировать даты заданий в месяце со случайным равномерным распределением. К примеру, для 10 человек 10 заданий так, чтобы даты отстояли друг от друга не менее, чем на два дня. Выходные и праздники не должны использоваться. По сути случайное равномерное распределение элементов в матрице с дополнительным условием, где матрица - месяц. Подскажите, где можно посмотреть алгоритм.

Comment: Пробовали ли вы написать его сами? Если да, то покажите код, и расскажите, что не получилось.

Comment: Какая же это матрица? Месяц - это вектор.

Comment: @andreycha Пробовал с использованием Random. Получается не совсем равномерное.

Comment: @Igor. Может и вектор. Я не математик. Но если для 10 человек, то мне кажется матрица, т.к. 10х30(31)

Comment: @S_Schmal - Какая разница, сколько человек? Между датами для разных людей есть связь?

Comment: @Igor Нет связи.

Comment: @andreycha Пример есть, но я не знаю, как его сюда выложить. А коду многовато.

Comment: @S_Schmal, а если нет связи между датами разных людей, почему нельзя сделать просто взять числа 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28 для 10 заданий, а для N заданий написать формулу вычисления (с учетом дополнительных условий в виде праздников и выходных)? Зачем нужен рандом?

Comment: @andreycha что значит взять? Для этого и нужен Random. По определенному алгоритму он и "берет" эти числа. Но вот затем получается, что для следующих людей эти числа повторяются.
А вот в формуле и проблема

Comment: @S_Schmal так между датами для разных людей есть связь? Сформулируйте на пальцах вопрос, что ли, приведите пример расписания.

Comment: @andreycha связи нет. Все случайно, но задача стоит "равномерно", т.е. желательно, чтобы не все 10 заданий в один день. Просто взять числа не получится, т.к. это могут быть выходные дни

Comment: Вы используете термин «[равномерное распределение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)» неверно. При истинном равномерном распределении расстояния между событиями могут быть как угодно малыми.

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил как-то так. Правда, сразу скажу, решение мне не очень нравится, но ничего лучшего придумать не смог. Параметры следующие:
tasksPerMonth - количество заданий в месяц, distanceBetweenTasks - минимальное расстояние между двумя соседними заданиями, isTasksInWeekend - учитывать или нет выходные, minDay - с этого дня начинаем (по разным причинам это может быть не первое число), listOfDays - изначально пустой, holidays - список выходных и праздничных дней, workdaysInMonth - список рабочих дней, random - пустой Random(). Остальное, я думаю, в принципе понятно, код функции OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks приведен ниже

```
        public void GenerateRandomTasks(int tasksPerMonth, int distanceBetweenTasks, bool isTasksInWeekend, int minDay, List<int> listOfDays, List<int> holidays, List<int> workdaysInMonth, Random random)
    {
        if (tasksPerMonth == 0)
            tasksPerMonth = 1;
        var daysInMonth = workdaysInMonth.Count + holidays.Count;
        var tasksDaysInMonth = !isTasksInWeekend ? workdaysInMonth.Count : daysInMonth;
        for (int i = 0; i < tasksPerMonth; i++)
        {
            int maxDayInPeriod;
            if (i < tasksPerMonth - 1)
            {
                maxDayInPeriod = minDay + tasksDaysInMonth / tasksPerMonth;
                if (!isTasksInWeekend && holidays.Contains(maxDayInPeriod))
                    maxDayInPeriod = workdaysInMonth.First(v => v > maxDayInPeriod);
            }
            else
            {
                maxDayInPeriod = daysInMonth;
                if (!isTasksInWeekend && holidays.Contains(maxDayInPeriod))
                    maxDayInPeriod = workdaysInMonth.Last();
            }

            if (minDay > maxDayInPeriod)
                minDay = maxDayInPeriod;

            var day = random.Next(minDay, maxDayInPeriod);

            if ((isTasksInWeekend != true && holidays.Contains(day)))
                day = OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks(minDay, maxDayInPeriod, listOfDays, day, holidays);

            if (day > daysInMonth)
                day = daysInMonth;

            listOfDays.Add(day);
            minDay = maxDayInPeriod;
            if (minDay <= day + distanceBetweenTasks)
                minDay = day + distanceBetweenTasks + 1;
        }
    }
```

Функция OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks

```
       private int OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks(int minDay, int maxDay, List<int> listDays, int day, List<int> holidays)
    {
        var listOfDays = new List<DaysForTaskPlan>();
        for (int k = minDay; k <= maxDay; k++)
        {
            var tempCountDays = listDays.Count(d => k == d);
            if (!holidays.Contains(k))
                listOfDays.Add(new DaysForTaskPlan(k, tempCountDays));
        }
        if (listOfDays.Any())
        {
            day = listOfDays.First(p => p.AmountDays == listOfDays.Min(z => z.AmountDays)).CurrDay;
        }
        listOfDays.Clear();
        return day;
    }
```

Всем удачи!